# SQLite GROUP BY on result of union not using indexes of constituent tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

With the following setup:

```
> CREATE TABLE test_table1(test_col INT NOT NULL);
> CREATE TABLE test_table2(test_col INT NOT NULL);
> CREATE INDEX test_index1 ON test_table1(test_col);
> CREATE INDEX test_index2 ON test_table2(test_col);
```

Doing a GROUP BY on a subquery referencing a single table uses its index, as expected:

```
> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM test_table1) GROUP BY test_col;
selectid  order  from  detail
--------  -----  ----  -------------------------------------------------------
0         0      0     SCAN TABLE test_table1 USING COVERING INDEX test_index1
```

But the same GROUP BY on the union of two tables, both of which have an index, results in two full table scans:

```
> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM test_table1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM test_table2) GROUP BY test_col;
selectid  order  from  detail
--------  -----  ----  ---------------------------------------
2         0      0     SCAN TABLE test_table1
3         0      0     SCAN TABLE test_table2
1         0      0     COMPOUND SUBQUERIES 2 AND 3 (UNION ALL)
0         0      0     SCAN SUBQUERY 1
0         0      0     USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
```

At least in theory, SQLite should be able to apply the grouping to each table in the union using that table's index, then merge the results into an overall result, right? Is there any way to hint that it should do this? I've tried adding INDEXED BYs to no avail.

Comment: Do not use `select *` with `group by`.  It just does not make sense, semantically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be possible that the database would be able to apply the grouping to each table – in theory. However, the problem is that the software must be able to prove that this transformation is always valid.

With the current optimizer implementation, this query cannot be flattened because it would violate [rule 17](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#flattening).